# How do i make a react native View sticky on scroll

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I've trying to get the backdrop button to stay sticky on the scroll and I tried a bunch of styling tricks and it still won't work. If you have any idea your help will be appreciated.

/>

```
            <View>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                    onPress={goBack}
                >
                    <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-dropleft-circle" size={50} color="#eb8900" style={styles.icon} />
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View>
        </ImageBackground>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take button out of `scrollview` or `flatlist`,

and use this styling for that button,

```
{
 position:'absolute',
 top:15//change it as per your need
 left:15 // same as above
}
```